# How to find a RibbonComboBox's child elements

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've declared a `RibbonComboBox` in my XAML.

```
<RibbonGroup Header="Category">
    <RibbonComboBox Name="cboCategory" Label="Category" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
        <RibbonGallery Name="galCategory">
            <RibbonGalleryCategory Name="catCategory" DisplayMemberPath="Text">
            </RibbonGalleryCategory>
        </RibbonGallery>
    </RibbonComboBox>
    <RibbonComboBox Name="cboSubcategory" Label="Subcategory:" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
        <RibbonGallery Name="galSubcategory">
            <RibbonGalleryCategory Name="catSubcategory" DisplayMemberPath="Text">
            </RibbonGalleryCategory>
        </RibbonGallery>
    </RibbonComboBox>
</RibbonGroup>
```

For reasons I don't fully understand, in order to manipulate items in the combo box, I need some members of `RibbonComboBox`, I need other members of `RibbonGallery` and some tasks require members of `RibbonGalleryCategory`.

So, given my instance of `RibbonComboBox`, how can I find the child `RibbonGallery` and `RibbonGalleryCategory` elements? There is no `Controls` or `Children` properties.

I found the following code on the web for finding the child elements of a control:

```
protected T GetChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj == null)
        return null;

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
        var result = (child as T) ?? GetChildOfType<T>(child);
        if (result != null)
            return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

However, while this code compiles, `VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount()` always returns 0 when I pass my combo box. So it is unable to find the control's children.

**EDIT:**

By the name `VisualTreeHelper`, I'm assuming this class is for finding visual elements, and perhaps the gallery is not a separate, visual element. So I guess I need to know how to traverse the child elements that are not visual?

Comment: Do you need an MVVM approach or just Code-Behind?

Comment: @lokusking: For now, I'm just trying to find the element from code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made two different approaches. One with your nested elements and one with just a simple ComboBox. The Buttons fill and read the `ComboBox` and `RibbonGalleryCategory`

**XAML**

```
  <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Fill me :)" Width="80" Height="20" Click="FillMe_OnClick"/>
            <Ribbon>
                <RibbonGroup Header="Category">
                    <RibbonComboBox Name="cboCategory" Label="Category" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
                        <ComboBoxItem>Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem>Item 2</ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem>Item 3</ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem>Item 4</ComboBoxItem>
                    </RibbonComboBox>
                    <RibbonComboBox Name="cboSubcategory" Label="Subcategory:" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
                        <RibbonGallery Name="galSubcategory">
                            <RibbonGalleryCategory Name="catSubcategory" DisplayMemberPath="Text">
                            </RibbonGalleryCategory>
                        </RibbonGallery>
                    </RibbonComboBox>
                </RibbonGroup>
            </Ribbon>
            <Button Content="Read me" Width="80" Height="20" Click="ReadMeCat_OnClick"></Button>
            <Button Content="Read me too" Width="80" Height="20" Click="ReadMeCombo_OnClick"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

**CodeBehind**

```
public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void FillMe_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.catSubcategory.Items.Add(new { Text = "Hello" });
            this.catSubcategory.Items.Add(new { Text = "World" });
            this.catSubcategory.Items.Add(new { Text = "Hello" });
            this.catSubcategory.Items.Add(new { Text = "Moon" });
        }

        private void ReadMeCat_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var result = catSubcategory.Items.Cast<dynamic>().Aggregate("", (current, xx) => (string) (current + (xx.Text + "\n")));
            MessageBox.Show(result);
        }

        private void ReadMeCombo_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var result = cboCategory.Items.Cast<ComboBoxItem>().Aggregate("", (current, xx) => current + (xx.Content.ToString() + "\n"));
            MessageBox.Show(result);
        }
```

**NOTE**

I think this doesnt need much explanation. If you still need one, call ;)

Be aware, that this is not how it should be done. WPF unleashes it true power with Bindings and MVVM. I can offer you such an example too.

**EDIT**

Yes you are right. The ComboBox-Items will be displayed but unable to select unless you use your `RibbonGalleryCategory`-Approach.

Another stupid thing about this stuff is, that `RibbonGallery` isnt actually a *real* Control. Its just an ItemsControl with an ControlTemplate, unable for the `VisualTreeHelper` to find.

In my opinion, using that controls makes everything more complicate if you dont use MVVM and DataBinding right from the start.

With DataBinding everything works like a charm. Unfortunately you will still have to use `RibbonGallery` and `RibbonGalleryCategory`. Or you place there simply a Ribbon-styled common ComboBox

**EDIT 2 -  A simple MVVM-Approach**

**Code**

```
public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        this.Ponies.Add(new Pony() { Id = 0, Color = Brushes.DeepSkyBlue, Name = "Slayer" });
        this.Ponies.Add(new Pony() { Id = 1, Color = Brushes.DeepPink, Name = "Murder" });
        this.Ponies.Add(new Pony() { Id = 2, Color = Brushes.Yellow, Name = "Brutal" });
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Pony> _ponies = new ObservableCollection<Pony>();
    private Pony _selectedPony;
    public ObservableCollection<Pony> Ponies => this._ponies;


    public Pony SelectedPony {
        get { return _selectedPony; }
        set {
            if (this._selectedPony == value) return;
            _selectedPony = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPony");
        }
    }
}

public class Pony : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    private string _name;

    public string Name {
        get { return this._name; }
        set {
            this._name = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public Brush Color { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="MyNameSpace.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        x:Name="root"
        Title="Try WPF!"
        mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Ribbon>
            <RibbonGroup Header="Category">
                <RibbonComboBox Label="Category" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" >
                    <RibbonGallery SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPony}">
                        <RibbonGalleryCategory ItemsSource="{Binding Ponies}" >
                            <RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Name="tb" Text="{Binding Name}" Background="{Binding Color}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                            </RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemTemplate>
                        </RibbonGalleryCategory>
                    </RibbonGallery>
                </RibbonComboBox>                
            </RibbonGroup>
        </Ribbon>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As you see as result, more power, less code :)

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't see where, given an instance of `cboSubcategory`, I can write code to find `galSubcategory`. I know I can reference the gallery directly, but I need to be able to find it from a reference to a `RibbonComboBox`.

Comment: I will be getting into MVVM--I've started learning that a little. But I really need to wrap up some code that I've started.

Comment: BTW, I also notice that when I populate the code as you did above that I am unable to select anything from the combo box. The items appear, and they highlight when I hover the mouse over them, but clicking a selection has no effect.

Comment: @JonathanWood Updated my insights

Comment: Thanks. I understand that I need to learn MVVM. But I cannot believe some of the trivial tasks that are so difficult under WPF. The fact that I can't seem to get a child element of a `RibbonComboBox` is just brain dead to me. I don't get it.

Comment: After 2 hours of diving into MVVM you will see that different. There are simply almost no needs anymore to manipulate Controls like in the old days. Leave the GUI-Business to GUI and focus on functionality. I'll Provide an example as edit

Comment: I started looking at your code, but a number of things about it seemed strange to me. Isn't it a bit unusual to use the `Window` class as the view model? And you derived your window class from `INotifyPropertyChanged` even though you have a separate `Pony` class.

Comment: Also, why the wrapper `Ponies` around `_ponies`?

Comment: You're absolute correct! thats NOT the proper way things should be done. Its just an example and i was about to show you the benefits of MVVM and **binding**. If you want a proper approach i can hand you one. That warpper ensures proper binding ;)

Comment: After everything failed that I tried, I'm trying to do some MVVM as you suggested. A question for you: how did you determine that the `ItemsSource` should be set for the `RibbonGalleryCategory` element, and that the `SelectedItem` should be set for the `RibbonGallery` element? A lot of those nested combo box elements have the same properties.

Comment: Well i just played around. Also i did something similar a long time ago. Thats the reason i never got really stuck with that whole Ribbon-business. In WPF a lot of controls can contain child-controls. But they named it `Items` because the need of binding whole control has gone. WPF differs between a logical and a visual tree. Most of the time the bound content represents the logical tree, as the visual tree just represents them as **you** wish. Make button look  like a textbox? No problem anymore. The switch from Forms to WPF looks hard in the beginning, but believe me it isnt ;)